# Does 'hot news' in present past tense contains 'recent past'?

Tags: grammar

In present perfect tense, Does 'hot news' in present past tense contains 'recent past'?
Let't take this sentence for example. "Malcolm X has just been assassinated."
Does the sentence mean hot news and recent past? Or It depends on the phrase?
I want to know that hot news contains recent past(so we can simultaneously call 'hot news' and 'recent past'?)

Comment: You're question is confusing, but "hot news" means whatever the person using the term says it means -- it's not a strictly-defined term.  (But I don't think that anyone could validly claim today that the assassination of Malcom X is "hot news", as that happened 51 years ago.)

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker, *if* I were to use ***hot news***, I would use it to mean something like "exciting news which broke within the last day or (possibly) week". It would be less immediate than *breaking news*.

Dictionary.com defines ***hot*** as "absolutely new; fresh" (sense 10, [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hot)), which may be derived from the expression "hot off the presses", as suggested by @Spagirl in her comment below. For me, this means within the last week. For others, it might be longer or shorter. But nobody would consider Malcolm X's assassination recent news.

Nor would *hot news* be synonymous with "recent past". I recently clipped my fingernails, but this is not hot news.

Some tabloid-like outlets declare their stories *hot news*, presumably with a wink to the hotness of the celebrities they relate to.

Comment: I imagine that 'hot news' is related to news being 'hot off the presses'. So it is news that has been published, but only very recently. It is very informal language.